# How to change layout so that it fits a tablet size screen?

Tags: android, xml

I have tested this app on mobile devices and the layout looks fine but when  tested it on a 7 inch tablet the main activity is missing textViews and images,the rest of the activities are fine though.

Could someone show me how to fix this situation as I'm sure its a fairly simple fix.The layout for the activity is shown below.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="271dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="0.68"
                android:src="@drawable/mark3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/depth_"
                android:textColor="#90f030"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ductDepth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/enter_duct_depth_mm"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Duct Depth:"
                android:textColor="#90f030"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/offDepth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/enter_offset_depth_mm"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Length:"
                android:textColor="#90f030"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/offLength"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/enter_offset_length_mm"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <!--
    This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
    titles for adjacent pages.
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llayout"
        android:background="@drawable/calcbttrans" />


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: Missing image and textboxes]
[image: What it should look like]

[image: Designer layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what exactly is the problem? the stretched image at the bottom?

if so, it's probably because you've set it to an exact size without allowing it the freedom to keep its aspect ratio. a possible solution is using 9-patch image or an xml drawable, or just keep the aspect ratio of the current image.

btw, the action bar doesn't look well. have you considered using the support library or actionBarSherlock? google already has guidelines about native look and feel (for example here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html )

---

EDIT: it seems the problem is on the layouts .

looks like the viewPager is on top of all the layouts, while the imageButton is beneath the linearLayout, when you scroll all the way to the bottom (not a native android UX, btw).

just check the UI designer and the outline . it clearly shows the problem (i had to replace all images since i don't have them, but this isn't the important thing) :

[image]

Comment: No that is a symptom of the problem,the main problem is that there should be three text boxes and labels as well as a diagram at the top of the activity.It shows up fine on phones but just not on tablets,I'm thinking its a problem with the layout because the rest of the activities are fine.

Comment: @BrianJ i see. but i think what you've published is a only a part of the layout file, and that it has a relative layout that has the viewPager cover everything in it instead of having rules. could you please show a sketch/screenshot of how it should look like, and not just how it shouldn't? it's very hard to understand what you are trying to have in the linearLayout. you could put it in an <include> tag to make things a bit clearer...

Comment: Okay @androiddeveloper , I will post this now in the edited question.

Comment: thanks for going to the trouble of testing this,I'm still not sure how exactly I can fix this,in the designer the viewPager is covering the textboxes as you say,but what steps do I have to take to fix the problem? I'm thinking I have to change the viewPager properties somehow? currently the height and width are set to `wrap content`

Comment: I added a screen shot to the question of the designer to better describe this.

Comment: first try to verify my theory, by removing/hiding the viewPager. then, if that's really the reason for the weird things, you should add rules to it (for example "layout_below" to put it below a specific view ). see this list of rules for RelativeLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html . alternatively, you can use the UI designer itself to make the rules by using your mouse (might be easier on some cases), so just drag the small filled rectangles (how do you name those in english?) to the views you wish to "stick" to, and that's it.

Comment: There is no viewPager on the rest of the activities and they display fine,maybe I dont need the viewPager item in the layout?

Comment: I set the height and width to `match parent` hopeully this will solve the issue.

Comment: You should decide what you need it to. you do know what a viewPager is, right? add it according to the design you wish to use...

Comment: if you set the height and width of the viewPager to match_parent, it will take as much space as it can...